# Is there any easy way to build the code in Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible

Python code:-

```
map = {
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    3: "three",
    4: "four",
    5: "five",
    6: "six",
    7: "seven"
}
IPS = ["192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2","192.168.0.3"]
count = len(IPS)
for ip in IPS:
    print("ip : " + ip + ": " + map[count])
    count += 1
```

I'm doing automation, and I wanted to make the above code as a playbook in Ansible. Any lead please?

Answer (score 0):

The below method worked for here. Not sure, this is a correct approach. But, this helps me for now.

```
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Test that my sample list module works
    sample:
    register: result

  - debug: var=result
```

You may need to have the script inside the folder "library", where the previous yml configuration will invoke the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *

def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec={})
    map = {
      1: "one",
      2: "two",
      3: "three",
      4: "four",
      5: "five",
      6: "six",
      7: "seven"
    }
    IPS = ["192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2","192.168.0.3"]
    count = len(IPS)
    ipArr = []
    for ip in IPS:
        ipArr.append("ip : " + ip + ": " + map[count])
    theReturnValue = {"count": count,"ips": IPS,"display": str(ipArr)}
    module.exit_json(changed=False, meta=theReturnValue)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Source:- https://medium.com/@auscunningham/write-a-ansible-module-with-python-527f0b292b4d

Thanks to Mr. Kumaresan (Market Simplified) on helping me with this.